# How to use composer to install dependencies for laravel?

Tags: laravel, dependencies, composer-php

I get the following errors while installing laravel using composer.
Please help me install laravel autoinstalling missing dependencies.

> symfony/var-dumper suggests installing ext-intl (To show region name
> in time zone dump) symfony/var-dumper suggests installing
> ext-symfony_debug () symfony/routing suggests installing
> doctrine/annotations (For using the annotation loader) symfony/routing
> suggests installing symfony/config (For using the all-in-one router or
> any loader) symfony/routing suggests installing
> symfony/dependency-injection (For loading routes from a service)
> symfony/routing suggests installing symfony/expression-language (For
> using expression matching) symfony/routing suggests installing
> symfony/yaml (For using the YAML loader) paragonie/random_compat
> suggests installing ext-libsodium (Provides a modern crypto API that
> can be used to generate random bytes.) symfony/event-dispatcher
> suggests installing symfony/dependency-injection ()
> symfony/http-kernel suggests installing symfony/browser-kit ()
> symfony/http-kernel suggests installing symfony/config ()
> symfony/http-kernel suggests installing symfony/dependency-injection
> () symfony/console suggests installing symfony/lock ()
> symfony/polyfill-intl-idn suggests installing ext-intl (For best
> performance) egulias/email-validator suggests installing ext-intl (PHP
> Internationalization Libraries are required to use the SpoofChecking
> validation) swiftmailer/swiftmailer suggests installing ext-intl
> (Needed to support internationalized email addresses)
> swiftmailer/swiftmailer suggests installing true/punycode (Needed to
> support internationalized email addresses, if ext-intl is not
> installed) ramsey/uuid suggests installing ircmaxell/random-lib
> (Provides RandomLib for use with the RandomLibAdapter) ramsey/uuid
> suggests installing ext-libsodium (Provides the PECL libsodium
> extension for use with the SodiumRandomGenerator) ramsey/uuid suggests
> installing ext-uuid (Provides the PECL UUID extension for use with the
> PeclUuidTimeGenerator and PeclUuidRandomGenerator) ramsey/uuid
> suggests installing moontoast/math (Provides support for converting
> UUID to 128-bit integer (in string form).) ramsey/uuid suggests
> installing ramsey/uuid-doctrine (Allows the use of Ramsey\Uuid\Uuid as
> Doctrine field type.) ramsey/uuid suggests installing
> ramsey/uuid-console (A console application for generating UUIDs with
> ramsey/uuid) symfony/translation suggests installing symfony/config ()
> symfony/translation suggests installing symfony/yaml () nesbot/carbon
> suggests installing friendsofphp/php-cs-fixer (Needed for the
> `composer phpcs` command. Allow to automatically fix code style.)
> nesbot/carbon suggests installing phpstan/phpstan (Needed for the
> `composer phpstan` command. Allow to detect potential errors.)
> monolog/monolog suggests installing aws/aws-sdk-php (Allow sending log
> messages to AWS services like DynamoDB) monolog/monolog suggests
> installing doctrine/couchdb (Allow sending log messages to a CouchDB
> server) monolog/monolog suggests installing ext-amqp (Allow sending
> log messages to an AMQP server (1.0+ required)) monolog/monolog
> suggests installing ext-mongo (Allow sending log messages to a MongoDB
> server) monolog/monolog suggests installing graylog2/gelf-php (Allow
> sending log messages to a GrayLog2 server) monolog/monolog suggests
> installing mongodb/mongodb (Allow sending log messages to a MongoDB
> server via PHP Driver) monolog/monolog suggests installing
> php-amqplib/php-amqplib (Allow sending log messages to an AMQP server
> using php-amqplib) monolog/monolog suggests installing
> php-console/php-console (Allow sending log messages to Google Chrome)
> monolog/monolog suggests installing rollbar/rollbar (Allow sending log
> messages to Rollbar) monolog/monolog suggests installing
> ruflin/elastica (Allow sending log messages to an Elastic Search
> server) monolog/monolog suggests installing sentry/sentry (Allow
> sending log messages to a Sentry server) league/flysystem suggests
> installing league/flysystem-aws-s3-v2 (Allows you to use S3 storage
> with AWS SDK v2) league/flysystem suggests installing
> league/flysystem-aws-s3-v3 (Allows you to use S3 storage with AWS SDK
> v3) league/flysystem suggests installing league/flysystem-azure
> (Allows you to use Windows Azure Blob storage) league/flysystem
> suggests installing league/flysystem-cached-adapter (Flysystem adapter
> decorator for metadata caching) league/flysystem suggests installing
> league/flysystem-eventable-filesystem (Allows you to use
> EventableFilesystem) league/flysystem suggests installing
> league/flysystem-rackspace (Allows you to use Rackspace Cloud Files)
> league/flysystem suggests installing league/flysystem-sftp (Allows you
> to use SFTP server storage via phpseclib) league/flysystem suggests
> installing league/flysystem-webdav (Allows you to use WebDAV storage)
> league/flysystem suggests installing league/flysystem-ziparchive
> (Allows you to use ZipArchive adapter) league/flysystem suggests
> installing spatie/flysystem-dropbox (Allows you to use Dropbox
> storage) league/flysystem suggests installing
> srmklive/flysystem-dropbox-v2 (Allows you to use Dropbox storage for
> PHP 5 applications) laravel/framework suggests installing
> aws/aws-sdk-php (Required to use the SQS queue driver and SES mail
> driver (~3.0).) laravel/framework suggests installing doctrine/dbal
> (Required to rename columns and drop SQLite columns (~2.5).)
> laravel/framework suggests installing guzzlehttp/guzzle (Required to
> use the Mailgun and Mandrill mail drivers and the ping methods on
> schedules (~6.0).) laravel/framework suggests installing
> league/flysystem-aws-s3-v3 (Required to use the Flysystem S3 driver
> (~1.0).) laravel/framework suggests installing
> league/flysystem-cached-adapter (Required to use Flysystem caching
> (~1.0).) laravel/framework suggests installing
> league/flysystem-rackspace (Required to use the Flysystem Rackspace
> driver (~1.0).) laravel/framework suggests installing nexmo/client
> (Required to use the Nexmo transport (~1.0).) laravel/framework
> suggests installing pda/pheanstalk (Required to use the beanstalk
> queue driver (~3.0).) laravel/framework suggests installing
> predis/predis (Required to use the redis cache and queue drivers
> (~1.0).) laravel/framework suggests installing
> pusher/pusher-php-server (Required to use the Pusher broadcast driver
> (~3.0).) laravel/framework suggests installing symfony/dom-crawler
> (Required to use most of the crawler integration testing tools
> (~3.3).) laravel/framework suggests installing
> symfony/psr-http-message-bridge (Required to psr7 bridging features
> (~1.0).) psy/psysh suggests installing ext-pdo-sqlite (The doc command
> requires SQLite to work.) psy/psysh suggests installing hoa/console (A
> pure PHP readline implementation. You'll want this if your PHP install
> doesn't already support readline or libedit.) filp/whoops suggests
> installing whoops/soap (Formats errors as SOAP responses)
> sebastian/global-state suggests installing ext-uopz (*)
> phpunit/phpunit-mock-objects suggests installing ext-soap (*)
> phpunit/php-code-coverage suggests installing ext-xdebug (^2.5.5)
> phpunit/phpunit suggests installing phpunit/php-invoker (^1.1)
> phpunit/phpunit suggests installing ext-xdebug (*)

Comment: These are not errors

Comment: No i meant that these are not the reason behind it not working. They are simply recommendations for other libraries :p

Answer (score 6):

You should run:

```
composer dump-autoload
```

and then try

```
composer install
```